# Is it a good practice for a module to recursively import its submodules?

Tags: python

I see a common pattern with Python modules. Sometimes `__init__.py` imports its submodules:

E.g.

```
mymod/
    __init__.py:
        from . import subm1, subm2
        __all__ = ['subm1', 'subm2']

    subm1.py:
        def subf1():
            ...
        __all__ = ['subf1']

    subm2.py:
        def subf2():
            ...
        __all__ = ['subf2']
```

So the client code only has to do this:

```
import mymod
mymod.subm1.subf1()
mymod.subm2.subf2()
```

Instead of:

```
import mymod.subm1
import mymod.subm2
mymod.subm1.subf1()
mymod.subm2.subf2()
```

Which one is The Best Practice<sup>TM</sup>? Is there anything wrong with the recursive import or should I stick to the default behaviour? What's the rationale for the default behaviour?

Comment: Both are valid design choices, but keep in mind that recursive imports will cause loading the package to get slower as it grows in size.

Answer (score 3):

This would depend on the usage of your module. If the submodules are just singleton objects that happen to be *written* as modules instead of having, eg, Java-like classes with all-static methods, recursive import is probably fine. On the other hand, if your module is grouping of several related sub modules (see, eg, the stdlib `html` module), you would want explicit submodule imports.

In general, a recursive import setup says "any client of this module will always want all of these". Consider whether that is true for your module (and other modules, case-by-case), and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Those practices are equal.

The first example expect both submodules have to be used together so there would be allways two imports in user code. Them you offer a shortcut.

The second one expect submodules are standalone blocks with only indirect interaction with others.